# Keycloak disable user after registration

Tags: keycloak, registration

I'm new to keycloak and I thought this would be super easy, but I can't find a solution. If a new user registrate, he should be disabled by default, till an admin enables the user manually. Is there a simple solution for that? Thank you in advance and best wishes!

Comment: Did you find a workaround to this?

Answer (score 0):

Create an SPI for `RegistrationUserCreation` where on `processResponse` you disable the user.

Then use this registration in the login flow.

Answer (score -5):

if you look at keycloak server page https://www.keycloak.org/docs/6.0/server_admin/

in `4.8. User Registration`, if a user is registered, he would not be disabled by default and there is no option for that. The only thing you can do is to require a few actions from user, like changing password or require email verification. Or you can disable the user from admin.

Think about it, if a new user goes through all the process to register just to be disabled y default, what's the point of enabling registration?